# How can I pass pyspark function and use it in another function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a function in pyspark that working but I want to separate this function into 2 functions.

I'm trying to pass the window spark function as an argument to another function.
one of the constraints is that my functions receive just columns and not df.

first of all this is my dataframe:

```
df2 = df.select(*cols, F.to_date("date").alias('datenew'))
```

so this is my function that working:

```
def price_col(df2, id_col, subcatid_col, start_date_col, year_col, statusid_col, price_col):
    window_spec_st = Window().partitionBy(F.col(id_col), F.col(subcatid_col)).orderBy(F.col(start_date_col))
    return new_df.where(
               (F.col(price_col) > F.lit(0)) & 
               (F.col(statusid_col) == F.lit(1)))\
        .withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(window_spec_st))\
        .where((F.col("row_number") == F.lit(1)))\
        .drop("row_number", "end_date", "end__date", start_date_col)
```

and this to separate to two different functions but its not working for me:

```
def set_windows_spec(id_col, subcatid_col, date_col, desc_order):
    order_by_col = F.col(date_col).desc() if desc_order else F.col(date_col).asc()
    return f'Window().partitionBy(F.col(id_col), F.col(subcatid_col)).orderBy(order_by_col)'


def conditions(price_col, statusid_col,id_col, subcatid_col, date_col,desc_order, set_windows_spec):
    return (F.when(
        (F.col(price_col) > F.lit(0)) &
        (F.col(statusid_col) == F.lit(1)),
         F.col(price_col))
            .withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(set_windows_spec(id_col, subcatid_col, date_col, desc_order)))
            .where(F.col("row_number") == F.lit(1))
            .alias("new_price_col"))
```

**thank you all for yours help!**

Comment: Your function set_window_spec returns a string, but over expects a WindowSpec. Furthermore, in conditions, the first expression is a Column, which does not have withColumn method.

Comment: If you want to use string inside the Spark function, you have to use it inside expr() function. Check https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-sql-expr-expression-function/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it to work by updating the return value from the set_window_spec function.

```
def set_windows_spec(id_col, subcatid_col, date_col, desc_order):
    order_by_col = F.col(date_col).desc() if desc_order else F.col(date_col).asc()
    return Window().partitionBy(F.col(id_col), F.col(subcatid_col)).orderBy(order_by_col)
```